# how to make multiple seo url using .htaccess?

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, seo

In index page I am bellow html form :

```
<form id="formname" class="form-inline" role="form" method="get" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars(SITE_URL.'location'); ?>">
</form>
```

In this page I have bellow js script :

```
$("#formname").submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var loc = $("#basic option:selected").text();
    window.location.href = url+ loc;
});
```

after submit this form the url is look like this :

> http://localhost/freelancer/chef/california

From this page : I am clicking this url : `menu-details?mid=2`

I want this url should be

> http://localhost/freelancer/chef/california/2/menuname

From this page I am clicking this url : `booking` page (it's a booking.php page)

From this page I am getting form name and value using `$_POST` method but I want the url should be look like this: (then I will use `$_GET` method)
`

> http://localhost/freelancer/chef/california/2/menuname/booking

Currently I am using following `.htaccess` rules but it's works only for first url not all url which I want.

**.htaccess**

```
ErrorDocument 404 /freelancer/chef/not-found.php
ErrorDocument 500 /freelancer/chef/not-found.php
RewriteEngine On        

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)$ city.php?city=$1    [NC,L] 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

**Updated :**

```
ErrorDocument 404 /freelancer/chef/not-found.php
ErrorDocument 500 /freelancer/chef/not-found.php
RewriteEngine On        

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)/?$ city.php?city=$1    [NC,L] 
#RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)/([\d]+)/([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)$ menu-details?mid=$2 [NC,L] 
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ menu-details.php?city=$1&mid=$2&title=$3
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Please, add this row:

```
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)/([\d]+)/([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)$ menu-details?mid=$2    [NC,L]
```

Comment: let me try with it

Comment: well, From first link page `http://localhost/freelancer/chef/california` (city.php) I am clicking this url `<?php echo SITE_URL."california/$mid/$link_title" ?>` but it's loading on `city.php` page. It should be load on 'menu-details.php' page

Comment: Well, I change it and it's working on menu-details page : `RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ menu-details.php?city=$1&mid=$2&title=$3`

Comment: Now the url is something like : `http://localhost/freelancer/chef/california/2/an-exploration-of-ramen` but if I put this url `http://localhost/freelancer/happiechef/california/` (see last forward slash) then it's showing me my custom error message. How can I accept `last forward slash` using `.htaccess` ?

Comment: I have updated my `.htaccess` rules. Now how can I go to booking.php from this link `http://localhost/freelancer/chef/california/2/an-exploration-of-ramen` ?